# Sourceforge svn checkout does not find trunk

Tags: svn, sourceforge

When I try to checkout the trunk of my repository on sourceforge, I get an error message, that the path does not exist. The trunk does definetly exist, and I double and triple checked for typos. When I check out the whole repository (tags, branches, trunk) Tortoise SVN does it without hesitation and voila, suddenly also the trunk folder is checked out.

Is this a known bug?

Also: I always have to type my password three times in a row for Tortoise SVN (or sourceforge) to accept it.

EDIT:

This checkout works:
`svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code`

This checkout does not work:
`svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code/trunk`
although trunk DEFINETLY exists. It seems to be a sourceforge problem. I am sorry, this will be merely a discussion, than a q&a. Is this totally misplaced here?

EDIT2:

As @David W. instructed I did got the info:

```
URL: svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code/MichaelKrebs/trunk 
Repository Root: svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code 
Repository UUID: 5725c7ca-164e-43f7-a85e-87d1503a1558 
Revision: 40 
Node Kind: directory 
Schedule: normal 
Last Changed Author: atrioom 
Last Changed Rev: 39 
Last Changed Date: 2011-11-09 01:20:08 +0100 (Mi, 09 Nov 2011)
```

Comment: Can you do a `svn co --depth=immediates svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code`? Then, cd to `trunk` and do a `svn up --set-depth=infinity .`? After doing that, you can do an svn info on trunk and see the URL, copy and paste and do the checkout again.

Comment: The path seems right. That confuses me even more. Okay, my first checkout was via Tortoise SVN. Now I could try checking out via command line (I head to teach subversion how to SSH to being able to follow your instructions). Maybe that works...

Comment: WAIT! lol, there it is. The right path right in front of my eyes. Thank you @DavidW. , that worked! I am just now checking out trunk using this URL: `svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code/MichaelKrebs/trunk`

Comment: Could you post your comment as answer so I can choose it as such? Or whats the neatest way to sum all that up?
Regards

Comment: no problem.  Posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a

```
svn co --depth=immediates svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code
```

Then, cd to trunk and do

```
svn up --set-depth=infinity
```

After doing that, you can do an `svn info` on trunk and see the URL, copy and paste and do the checkout again.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is wrong. Yes, trunk exists, but not under `code` - it is under `MichaelKrebs`.

I used anonymous access to look there:

```
$ svn ls svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code
MichaelKrebs/

$ svn ls svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code/MichaelKrebs
branch/
tags/
trunk/

$ svn ls svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code/MichaelKrebs/trunk
.htaccess
.project
404.html
crossdomain.xml
css/
images/
includes/
index.php
js/
robots.txt
```

So, your desired url must be this:

```
svn+ssh://atrioom@svn.code.sf.net/p/michaelkrebs/code/MichaelKrebs/trunk
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. Seems like you just informed me, that anonymous has access at all. Sourceforge says no one has, except me. Regarding the url-issue, I figured out the right path with @DavidW.s help yesterday.

Comment: I believed SF is only supporting *open*source repos, ie. with readonly access to anyone; do they really promise private repos? Can you post a link?

Comment: If you create a project and add SVN, you can edit permissions here:
`https://sourceforge.net/p/YOUR_PROJECT/admin/tools`
In the `Read` tab there is only `Admin`, so I thought anonymous is disabled. Well I don't really care, but it's good to know :P